# SVG polar gradients

Tags: svg, gradient, polar-coordinates

I'm a beginner at SVG, but I'd like to learn some techniques.

To be short, is there a simple way to create something like this?

[image: A common spinner]

I was thinking about creating a polar gradient and then clipping it:

[image: Polar gradient]

But how do I generate a polar gradient?

Even if there's no native method, maybe it could be made with a simple linear gradient and then using some rectangular-polar coordinate transformation. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So this is the solution I developed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"> 
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" onload="makeGradient();">
    <script>
        function makeGradient() {
            var root = document.rootElement, i = 256, cir, a;
            for (; i--;) {
                a = i*Math.PI/128;
                cir = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
                cir.setAttribute("cx", 50 - Math.sin(a)*45);
                cir.setAttribute("cy", 50 - Math.cos(a)*45);
                cir.setAttribute("r", "5");
                cir.setAttribute("fill", "rgb(" + i + ", " + i + ", " + i + ")");
                root.appendChild(cir);
            }
        }
    </script>
</svg>
```

Minified version (395 bytes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" version="1.1" onload="g(this.namespaceURI,document,Math)"><script>function g(n,d,m,i,c,a,p,z){for(i=256;i--;){a=i*m.PI/128;c=d.createElementNS(n,"circle");for(p in z={cx:10-m.sin(a)*9,cy:10-m.cos(a)*9,r:1,fill:"rgb("+[i,i,i]+")"})c.setAttribute(p,z[p]);d.rootElement.appendChild(c)}}</script></svg>
```

This was made creating circles filled with 256 shades of gray (it sounds like porn literature for coders!) and conveniently placed.

The radii can be adjusted: I've chosen 45 for the whole spinner and 5 for the single circles. Moreover, the detail can be adjusted too if 256 are too many:

```
for (; i -= 2;) { ...
```

Use powers of 2 for optimal results. Or just define the number of steps:

```
var steps = 100, i = steps;
for (; i--;) {
    a = i*2*Math.PI/steps;
    ...
    cir.setAttribute("fill", "rgb(" + i*255/steps + ", " + ...);
}
```

A big "thank you" to Erik Dahlström for the hint, and thank you Michael Mullany for the attempt :)

**Edit:** [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RichieHindle/eyrej/) to demonstrate the code.

**Edit 2:** [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUDkL/7/) using curved segments to create the spinner. You can adjust the number of segments and the size, and even see it spinning. I don't know why when the size is auto, there's a bottom margin of 5 pixels on the SVG, this making the spinning slightly off-centered...

Comment: You might find you get better performance if you used canvas for this if all you're doing is creating the image.

Comment: @RobertLongson To be honest I haven't checked the performances. Can you suggest some tool to do so? I'm not sure jsperf would be good for that...

Answer (score 2):

There are no paintservers in SVG 1.1 that allow this directly, but you can e.g do it using a bit of script. [Here's an article](http://web.archive.org/web/20200722073945/http://owl3d.com/svg/tubefy/articles/article3.html) that explains how.

Comment: Interesting article, definitely worth a read. Using some dynamially generated shapes was the other solution I had in mind, but I was wondering about the performances. I'm going to do some tests.

Comment: I've created an answer, you may want to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for polar gradients in SVG 1.1 (what's available in most edge browsers today) although there are proposals to allow capabilities like these in SVG 2. The only workaround I can think of is to apply a blend filter using an externally generated image as your multiply source. But then, I'm assuming the whole point it to try to avoid external images so this would be a little pointless:)

Comment: You got the point man :) That's a spinner, so having the browers making no requests would be great, since there wouldn't be serving problem with the subsequent AJAX request. Using data URIs would be the next solution, but I think an SVGs would be perfect since, you know, vectors and all...