# triangles bordered by an inner and outer circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create about twelve triangles inside a circle (each having an arc of 360/12 = 30 degrees) using CSS3 such that their bottom borders fit the arc of the outer circle, and their peaks fit/curve around the inner circle. My initial idea was to create each triangle and then position it within the two circles. But using the simple triangle-creation method in CSS, I can't figure out how to create a triangle with borders that fit the two circles exactly.  These triangles need to have text inside them later (and styled etc.) and be moved using jQuery or JavaScript (I haven't figured that part out completely yet). Could anyone give me any ideas ? How can I go about doing this. Also, whether this is the best way to go about it , especially if I later want to drag them as a group within the two circles using jQuery. I am new to CSS/JavaScript/jQuery, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The following is a simple snippet of code for the two circles.

```css
.outerCircle {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:50%;
    
}

.innerCircle {
  position:relative;
  left:170px;
  top:170px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid black;
  
}

.triangleOne {
 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="outerCircle">
  <div class="triangleOne" ></div>
  <div class="triangleTwo" ></div>
  <div class="triangleThree"> </div>
  <div class="triangleFour" ></div >
  <div class="triangleFive"> </div>
  <div class="triangleSix"> </div>
  <div class="triangleSeven"> </div>
  <div class="triangleEight"> </div>
  <div class="triangleNine" ></div>
  <div class="triangleTen"> </div>
  <div class="triangleEleven"> </div>
  <div class="triangleTwelve" ></div>
  
  <div class="innerCircle"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: How do you plan to make a triangle? Using an image? Canvas? SVG? Or just CSS, as explained [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ Helps you to create Triangle

Comment: I prefer using CSS, because I need to style them later. But I am also open to other ideas if they'll make this better or easy to do. I have tried to create triangles using CSS, but the problem I am getting is I can't figure out how to exactly define the borders such that they curve around the arcs of the circles. Also, I need to highlight the borders of the triangles for styling, which seems impossible using the basic triangle creation method, whereby you create the triangle using borders of a div.

Comment: Watch out, you're pretty limited styling pure CSS triangles. All you can do is to change the color of the triangle, and adding a fake border putting another triangle over it (maybe using a pseudo-element). Anyway, is [this](http://jsbin.com/xuqid/1/edit) what you're trying to create?

Comment: @MaxArt: That was neat. But creating triangles with border and without using extra pseudo-elements is possible by using a rotated element (say 45deg) and making two borders transparent. But the problem is it will give border on only 2 sides the border on the other side may need to be done with probably a 45deg linear gradient. But overall I think this is a bit too complex for CSS. SVG  might be a better idea.

Comment: @MaxArt Thanks, this looks really cool. What I had in mind was that triangles fit inside the two circles, touching each other's and the circles' borders without those spaces in between, but I could work with this too. Could you please let me know how did you arrive at the 165px and 52px values of the top and right/left borders and the transform-origin values? Also, do you think there is a way to somehow style the spaces in between. I am going to look into SVG, can they be styled using all the CSS styling properties, like colors or gradients or borders or shadows ? Thanks once again!

Comment: @QPTR To get 52px and 165px I used some basic geometry (actually got 163, but adjusted because of roundings and borders), not even trigonometry. SVG allows you to draw any shape you want, fill it with whatever you want, style them with CSS and as a plus [if the browser supports `transform`](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d), you can be sure [it supports SVG too](http://caniuse.com/svg), so it'd definitely be a better choice. About the definitive result, can you attach a picture of what you want to achieve? It's not easy to understand with words only.

Comment: @MaxArt [Here](http://oi58.tinypic.com/mjprph.jpg) is a very basic idea  (ignore the no. of triangles and colors) I want to create a series of triangles with months displayed, and then drag them circularly around. Any one of the months is dragged to the 45deg point which indicates that its been selected. I wanted to give a circular mandala like effect to it, so thats gonna involve lots of styling (also give them 3D-effect with shadows), and using jQuery draggable to drag all the triangular panels around as a group. What do you think, is this all possible with SVG?

Comment: @QPTR Oh I get it now, what you actually want, it's actually a series of *sectors of an annulus*. Right, preparing an answer using SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this [old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149286/svg-polar-gradients) for an unrelated topic, but one of the solutions I developed actually fits your needs quite well. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/pUDkL/7/), in particular, is a fiddle with the basic.

The markup is a little different, but basically the same:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" version="1.1">
    <path d="M 200,0 A 200 200,0,0,1,300,26.794919243112258 L 215,174.01923788646684 A 30 30,0,0,0,200,170"/>
    <path d="M 300,26.794919243112258 A 200 200,0,0,1,373.2050807568877,100 L 225.98076211353316,185 A 30 30,0,0,0,215,174.01923788646684"/>
    ...
</svg>
```

You can style the sectors easily with CSS:

```
path {
    fill: red;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

But there's more you can do with SVG, like gradients and all. You can use even text.

**[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/rapili/1/edit)**

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! The path tag is where you are defining all the triangles, right? I am going to read up a little on SVG to know about all those parameters you are giving to the path tag, any help would be appreciated :) Also, can animations, and jQuery be also applied to SVGs ? Anyway, you've totally given me a direction of where to proceed from. Thanks a lot once again!

Comment: PS: I just read up on the path tag, that is some very awesome stuff. So, now I understand the first A to be creating the larger outer arc and the the other A as the smaller inner one, and the L as the line that cuts across. One more question, how did you arrive at the exact values to create the arcs and lines?

Comment: @QPTR This time I had to use some trigonometry, indeed. Nothing complicated, actually. I've linked a fiddle in the answer that shows a dynamically generated SVG with Javascript. Once the paths have been created, I just copied the content of the `<svg>` element :) And yes, you *can* use jQuery to animate an SVG, and even use [CSS animations](http://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) for the task.

Comment: Ah, ohkay, I better learn how to calculate the values then :) Thanks a lot for your awesome help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to make a circle out of multiple triangles:

```
.triangle { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 150px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 150px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 200px solid red; 
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%; }
.One {
    top: 0px;
    left: 50px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

adjust every single triangle just by the rotation and position. After a few adjustments you should get what you want.
See my example on

```
JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcusrommel/20df94wo/1/
```

Comment: Aha! So you create the triangles, and then give the inner circle a higher z-index, thats a cool idea. I experimented with this a bit too, but now I need to think about SVG because I want to give quite detailed styling to each of the panels which seems impossible with the border property. Thanks!